# Get first index from multiindex grouping by level

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a multiindex pandas dataframe:

```
                              SHOPPING_COUNT  
CLIENT          YEAR MONTH               
1000063         2013 12             9  
                2014 1              9  
                     2              7  
                     3              9  
                2015 4              6  
                     5              5  
                     6              9  
1001327         2014 5              1  
                     6              1  
                2015 2              7  
                     3              1  
                     4              3 
1001399         2013 8              1
```

And I would to know the first index of each client, ordering by level 0.
I mean, I would want to get:

```
1000063         2013 12
1001327         2014 5
1001399         2013 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `df` be your dataframe, you can do something like:

```
df = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0:1])
df.index = df.index.droplevel(0)
```

actually this should be more easy to do maybe, but I think that this method works.

Comment: Probably, it isn't the easiest, nor the fastest, but effective. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not very programmatic, but if you look at the result of:

```
client = 1000063
df.loc[client].index
```

Then the following would work:

```
year  = df.loc[client].index.levels[0][df.loc[client].index.labels[0][0]]
month = df.loc[client].index.levels[1][df.loc[client].index.labels[1][0]]
```